# get element height inside flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I was hoping you could help me with this. I am trying to use some javascript to find the height of an element inside of a flexslider

. There are two catches. When I try a regular

```
function getHeight(){
var h = document.getElementById("id-height").style.height;
alert(h + " px");
```

with a body onload="getHeight()" the height that I get on the element is not coming up. I am guessing because the function is being called before all the elements in the slider load but that's just a guess. The other catch is that I need to recall the function every time the slider changes pictures. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to add a top margin on an element inside a flexslider so that it is middle-aligned vertically. To see what I'm talking about, please go to http://evergreenbusinessbuilders.businesscatalyst.com and look at the main slider at the very top under the navigation.

Here is the jquery for the slider (as i got it from woothemes):

```
/*
* jQuery FlexSlider v1.8
* http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
*
* Copyright 2012 WooThemes
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*
* Contrib: Darin Richardson
*/

;(function ($) {

//FlexSlider: Object Instance
$.flexslider = function(el, options) {
var slider = el;

slider.init = function() {
slider.vars = $.extend({}, $.flexslider.defaults, options);
slider.data('flexslider', true);
slider.container = $('.slides', slider).first();
slider.slides = $('.slides:first > li', slider);
slider.count = slider.slides.length;
slider.animating = false;
slider.currentSlide = slider.vars.slideToStart;
slider.animatingTo = slider.currentSlide;
slider.atEnd = (slider.currentSlide == 0) ? true : false;
slider.eventType = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
slider.cloneCount = 0;
slider.cloneOffset = 0;
slider.manualPause = false;
slider.vertical = (slider.vars.slideDirection == "vertical");
slider.prop = (slider.vertical) ? "top" : "marginLeft";
slider.args = {};

//Test for webbkit CSS3 Animations
slider.transitions = "webkitTransition" in document.body.style;
if (slider.transitions) slider.prop = "-webkit-transform";

//Test for controlsContainer
if (slider.vars.controlsContainer != "") {
slider.controlsContainer = $(slider.vars.controlsContainer).eq($('.slides').index(slider.container));
slider.containerExists = slider.controlsContainer.length > 0;
}
//Test for manualControls
if (slider.vars.manualControls != "") {
slider.manualControls = $(slider.vars.manualControls, ((slider.containerExists) ? slider.controlsContainer : slider));
slider.manualExists = slider.manualControls.length > 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FlexSlider: Randomize Slides
if (slider.vars.randomize) {
slider.slides.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });
slider.container.empty().append(slider.slides);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FlexSlider: Slider Animation Initialize
if (slider.vars.animation.toLowerCase() == "slide") {
if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(0);
}
slider.css({"overflow": "hidden"});
if (slider.vars.animationLoop) {
slider.cloneCount = 2;
slider.cloneOffset = 1;
slider.container.append(slider.slides.filter(':first').clone().addClass('clone')).prepend(slider.slides.filter(':last').clone().addClass('clone'));
}
//create newSlides to capture possible clones
slider.newSlides = $('.slides:first > li', slider);
var sliderOffset = (-1 * (slider.currentSlide + slider.cloneOffset));
if (slider.vertical) {
slider.newSlides.css({"display": "block", "width": "100%", "float": "left"});
slider.container.height((slider.count + slider.cloneCount) * 200 + "%").css("position", "absolute").width("100%");
//Timeout function to give browser enough time to get proper height initially
setTimeout(function() {
slider.css({"position": "relative"}).height(slider.slides.filter(':first').height());
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.transitions) ? "translate3d(0," + sliderOffset * slider.height() + "px,0)" : sliderOffset * slider.height() + "px";
slider.container.css(slider.args);
}, 100);

} else {
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.transitions) ? "translate3d(" + sliderOffset * slider.width() + "px,0,0)" : sliderOffset * slider.width() + "px";
slider.container.width((slider.count + slider.cloneCount) * 200 + "%").css(slider.args);
//Timeout function to give browser enough time to get proper width initially
setTimeout(function() {
slider.newSlides.width(slider.width()).css({"float": "left", "display": "block"});
}, 100);
}

} else { //Default to fade
//Not supporting fade CSS3 transitions right now
slider.transitions = false;
slider.slides.css({"width": "100%", "float": "left", "marginRight": "-100%"}).eq(slider.currentSlide).fadeIn(slider.vars.animationDuration); 
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FlexSlider: Control Nav
if (slider.vars.controlNav) {
if (slider.manualExists) {
slider.controlNav = slider.manualControls;
} else {
var controlNavScaffold = $('<ol class="flex-control-nav"></ol>');
var j = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < slider.count; i++) {
controlNavScaffold.append('<li><a>' + j + '</a></li>');
j++;
}

if (slider.containerExists) {
$(slider.controlsContainer).append(controlNavScaffold);
slider.controlNav = $('.flex-control-nav li a', slider.controlsContainer);
} else {
slider.append(controlNavScaffold);
slider.controlNav = $('.flex-control-nav li a', slider);
}
}

slider.controlNav.eq(slider.currentSlide).addClass('active');

slider.controlNav.bind(slider.eventType, function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
(slider.controlNav.index($(this)) > slider.currentSlide) ? slider.direction = "next" : slider.direction = "prev";
slider.flexAnimate(slider.controlNav.index($(this)), slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
}
});
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Direction Nav
if (slider.vars.directionNav) {
var directionNavScaffold = $('<ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="prev" href="#">' + slider.vars.prevText + '</a></li><li><a class="next" href="#">' + slider.vars.nextText + '</a></li></ul>');

if (slider.containerExists) {
$(slider.controlsContainer).append(directionNavScaffold);
slider.directionNav = $('.flex-direction-nav li a', slider.controlsContainer);
} else {
slider.append(directionNavScaffold);
slider.directionNav = $('.flex-direction-nav li a', slider);
}

//Set initial disable styles if necessary
if (!slider.vars.animationLoop) {
if (slider.currentSlide == 0) {
slider.directionNav.filter('.prev').addClass('disabled');
} else if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1) {
slider.directionNav.filter('.next').addClass('disabled');
}
}

slider.directionNav.bind(slider.eventType, function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var target = ($(this).hasClass('next')) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');

if (slider.canAdvance(target)) {
slider.flexAnimate(target, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
}
});
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Keyboard Nav
if (slider.vars.keyboardNav && $('ul.slides').length == 1) {
function keyboardMove(event) {
if (slider.animating) {
return;
} else if (event.keyCode != 39 && event.keyCode != 37){
return;
} else {
if (event.keyCode == 39) {
var target = slider.getTarget('next');
} else if (event.keyCode == 37){
var target = slider.getTarget('prev');
}

if (slider.canAdvance(target)) {
slider.flexAnimate(target, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
}
}
}
$(document).bind('keyup', keyboardMove);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FlexSlider: Mousewheel interaction
if (slider.vars.mousewheel) {
slider.mousewheelEvent = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
slider.bind(slider.mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e = e ? e : window.event;
var wheelData = e.detail ? e.detail * -1 : e.wheelDelta / 40,
target = (wheelData < 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');

if (slider.canAdvance(target)) {
slider.flexAnimate(target, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
}
});
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Slideshow Setup
if (slider.vars.slideshow) {
//pauseOnHover
if (slider.vars.pauseOnHover && slider.vars.slideshow) {
slider.hover(function() {
slider.pause();
}, function() {
if (!slider.manualPause) {
slider.resume();
}
});
}

//Initialize animation
slider.animatedSlides = setInterval(slider.animateSlides, slider.vars.slideshowSpeed);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Pause/Play
if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
var pausePlayScaffold = $('<div class="flex-pauseplay"><span></span></div>');

if (slider.containerExists) {
slider.controlsContainer.append(pausePlayScaffold);
slider.pausePlay = $('.flex-pauseplay span', slider.controlsContainer);
} else {
slider.append(pausePlayScaffold);
slider.pausePlay = $('.flex-pauseplay span', slider);
}

var pausePlayState = (slider.vars.slideshow) ? 'pause' : 'play';
slider.pausePlay.addClass(pausePlayState).text((pausePlayState == 'pause') ? slider.vars.pauseText : slider.vars.playText);

slider.pausePlay.bind(slider.eventType, function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if ($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
slider.pause();
slider.manualPause = true;
} else {
slider.resume();
slider.manualPause = false;
}
});
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider:Touch Swip Gestures
//Some brilliant concepts adapted from the following sources
//Source: TouchSwipe - http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library
//Source: SwipeJS - http://swipejs.com
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
//For brevity, variables are named for x-axis scrolling
//The variables are then swapped if vertical sliding is applied
//This reduces redundant code...I think :)
//If debugging, recognize variables are named for horizontal scrolling
var startX,
startY,
offset,
cwidth,
dx,
startT,
scrolling = false;

slider.each(function() {
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
this.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
}
});

function onTouchStart(e) {
if (slider.animating) {
e.preventDefault();
} else if (e.touches.length == 1) {
slider.pause();
cwidth = (slider.vertical) ? slider.height() : slider.width();
startT = Number(new Date());
offset = (slider.vertical) ? (slider.currentSlide + slider.cloneOffset) * slider.height() : (slider.currentSlide + slider.cloneOffset) * slider.width();
startX = (slider.vertical) ? e.touches[0].pageY : e.touches[0].pageX;
startY = (slider.vertical) ? e.touches[0].pageX : e.touches[0].pageY;
slider.setTransition(0);

this.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
this.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);
}
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
dx = (slider.vertical) ? startX - e.touches[0].pageY : startX - e.touches[0].pageX;
scrolling = (slider.vertical) ? (Math.abs(dx) < Math.abs(e.touches[0].pageX - startY)) : (Math.abs(dx) < Math.abs(e.touches[0].pageY - startY));

if (!scrolling) {
e.preventDefault();
if (slider.vars.animation == "slide" && slider.transitions) {
if (!slider.vars.animationLoop) {
dx = dx/((slider.currentSlide == 0 && dx < 0 || slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1 && dx > 0) ? (Math.abs(dx)/cwidth+2) : 1);
}
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + (-offset - dx) + "px,0)": "translate3d(" + (-offset - dx) + "px,0,0)";
slider.container.css(slider.args);
}
}
}

function onTouchEnd(e) {
slider.animating = false;
if (slider.animatingTo == slider.currentSlide && !scrolling && !(dx == null)) {
var target = (dx > 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');
if (slider.canAdvance(target) && Number(new Date()) - startT < 550 && Math.abs(dx) > 20 || Math.abs(dx) > cwidth/2) {
slider.flexAnimate(target, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
} else {
slider.flexAnimate(slider.currentSlide, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
}
}

//Finish the touch by undoing the touch session
this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
this.removeEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);
startX = null;
startY = null;
dx = null;
offset = null;
}
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Resize Functions (If necessary)
if (slider.vars.animation.toLowerCase() == "slide") {
$(window).resize(function(){
if (!slider.animating) {
if (slider.vertical) {
slider.height(slider.slides.filter(':first').height());
slider.args[slider.prop] = (-1 * (slider.currentSlide + slider.cloneOffset))* slider.slides.filter(':first').height() + "px";
if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(0);
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0,0)";
}
slider.container.css(slider.args);
} else {
slider.newSlides.width(slider.width());
slider.args[slider.prop] = (-1 * (slider.currentSlide + slider.cloneOffset))* slider.width() + "px";
if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(0);
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0,0)";
}
slider.container.css(slider.args);
}
}
});
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FlexSlider: Destroy the slider entity
//Destory is not included in the minified version right now, but this is a working function for anyone who wants to include it.
//Simply bind the actions you need from this function into a function in the start() callback to the event of your chosing
/*
slider.destroy = function() {
slider.pause();
if (slider.controlNav && slider.vars.manualControls == "") slider.controlNav.closest('.flex-control-nav').remove();
if (slider.directionNav) slider.directionNav.closest('.flex-direction-nav').remove();
if (slider.vars.pausePlay) slider.pausePlay.closest('.flex-pauseplay').remove();
if (slider.vars.keyboardNav && $('ul.slides').length == 1) $(document).unbind('keyup', keyboardMove);
if (slider.vars.mousewheel) slider.unbind(slider.mousewheelEvent);
if (slider.transitions) slider.each(function(){this.removeEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);});
if (slider.vars.animation == "slide" && slider.vars.animationLoop) slider.newSlides.filter('.clone').remove();
if (slider.vertical) slider.height("auto");
slider.slides.hide();
slider.removeData('flexslider');
}
*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//FlexSlider: start() Callback
slider.vars.start(slider);
}

//FlexSlider: Animation Actions
slider.flexAnimate = function(target, pause) {
if (!slider.animating) {
//Animating flag
slider.animating = true;

//FlexSlider: before() animation Callback
slider.animatingTo = target;
slider.vars.before(slider);

//Optional paramter to pause slider when making an anmiation call
if (pause) {
slider.pause();
}

//Update controlNav   
if (slider.vars.controlNav) {
slider.controlNav.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

//Is the slider at either end
slider.atEnd = (target == 0 || target == slider.count - 1) ? true : false;
if (!slider.vars.animationLoop && slider.vars.directionNav) {
if (target == 0) {
slider.directionNav.removeClass('disabled').filter('.prev').addClass('disabled');
} else if (target == slider.count - 1) {
slider.directionNav.removeClass('disabled').filter('.next').addClass('disabled');
} else {
slider.directionNav.removeClass('disabled');
}
}

if (!slider.vars.animationLoop && target == slider.count - 1) {
slider.pause();
//FlexSlider: end() of cycle Callback
slider.vars.end(slider);
}

if (slider.vars.animation.toLowerCase() == "slide") {
var dimension = (slider.vertical) ? slider.slides.filter(':first').height() : slider.slides.filter(':first').width();

if (slider.currentSlide == 0 && target == slider.count - 1 && slider.vars.animationLoop && slider.direction != "next") {
slider.slideString = "0px";
} else if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1 && target == 0 && slider.vars.animationLoop && slider.direction != "prev") {
slider.slideString = (-1 * (slider.count + 1)) * dimension + "px";
} else {
slider.slideString = (-1 * (target + slider.cloneOffset)) * dimension + "px";
}
slider.args[slider.prop] = slider.slideString;

if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(slider.vars.animationDuration); 
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + slider.slideString + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + slider.slideString + ",0,0)";
slider.container.css(slider.args).one("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend", function(){
slider.wrapup(dimension);
});   
} else {
slider.container.animate(slider.args, slider.vars.animationDuration, function(){
slider.wrapup(dimension);
});
}
} else { //Default to Fade
slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).fadeOut(slider.vars.animationDuration);
slider.slides.eq(target).fadeIn(slider.vars.animationDuration, function() {
slider.wrapup();
});
}
}
}

//FlexSlider: Function to minify redundant animation actions
slider.wrapup = function(dimension) {
if (slider.vars.animation == "slide") {
//Jump the slider if necessary
if (slider.currentSlide == 0 && slider.animatingTo == slider.count - 1 && slider.vars.animationLoop) {
slider.args[slider.prop] = (-1 * slider.count) * dimension + "px";
if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(0);
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0,0)";
}
slider.container.css(slider.args);
} else if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1 && slider.animatingTo == 0 && slider.vars.animationLoop) {
slider.args[slider.prop] = -1 * dimension + "px";
if (slider.transitions) {
slider.setTransition(0);
slider.args[slider.prop] = (slider.vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + slider.args[slider.prop] + ",0,0)";
}
slider.container.css(slider.args);
}
}
slider.animating = false;
slider.currentSlide = slider.animatingTo;
//FlexSlider: after() animation Callback
slider.vars.after(slider);
}

//FlexSlider: Automatic Slideshow
slider.animateSlides = function() {
if (!slider.animating) {
slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
}
}

//FlexSlider: Automatic Slideshow Pause
slider.pause = function() {
clearInterval(slider.animatedSlides);
if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
slider.pausePlay.removeClass('pause').addClass('play').text(slider.vars.playText);
}
}

//FlexSlider: Automatic Slideshow Start/Resume
slider.resume = function() {
slider.animatedSlides = setInterval(slider.animateSlides, slider.vars.slideshowSpeed);
if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
slider.pausePlay.removeClass('play').addClass('pause').text(slider.vars.pauseText);
}
}

//FlexSlider: Helper function for non-looping sliders
slider.canAdvance = function(target) {
if (!slider.vars.animationLoop && slider.atEnd) {
if (slider.currentSlide == 0 && target == slider.count - 1 && slider.direction != "next") {
return false;
} else if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1 && target == 0 && slider.direction == "next") {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
} else {
return true;
}  
}

//FlexSlider: Helper function to determine animation target
slider.getTarget = function(dir) {
slider.direction = dir;
if (dir == "next") {
return (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1) ? 0 : slider.currentSlide + 1;
} else {
return (slider.currentSlide == 0) ? slider.count - 1 : slider.currentSlide - 1;
}
}

//FlexSlider: Helper function to set CSS3 transitions
slider.setTransition = function(dur) {
slider.container.css({'-webkit-transition-duration': (dur/1000) + "s"});
}

//FlexSlider: Initialize
slider.init();
}

//FlexSlider: Default Settings
$.flexslider.defaults = {
animation: "fade",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
slideDirection: "horizontal",   //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
slideshowSpeed: 6000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
animationDuration: 600,         //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
keyboardNav: true,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
mousewheel: false,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via mousewheel
prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
pauseText: 'Pause',             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
playText: 'Play',               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item
randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
slideToStart: 0,                //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
animationLoop: true,            //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
pauseOnAction: false,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
pauseOnHover: false,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
controlsContainer: "",          //Selector: Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the flexSlider element. Example use would be ".flexslider-container", "#container", etc. If the given element is not found, the default action will be taken.
manualControls: "",             //Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Example would be ".flex-control-nav li" or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
end: function(){}               //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
}

//FlexSlider: Plugin Function
$.fn.flexslider = function(options) {
return this.each(function() {
if ($(this).find('.slides li').length == 1) {
$(this).find('.slides li').fadeIn(400);
}
else if ($(this).data('flexslider') != true) {
new $.flexslider($(this), options);
}
});
}  

})(jQuery);
```

As always, thank you.

Comment: how are you invoking the function

Answer (score 1):

do this instead

```
var result = document.getElementById("id-height").offsetHeight;

alert(result + " px");
```

pure js raw solution.

jquery

```
var result = $("#id-height").height(); 
alert(result + " px");
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions @nol. Now i'm getting a height. Right now I'm calling the function with a <body "onload=getHeight()">, but how do I call the function every time the slider changes pictures? I have added the flexslider jquery above.

Comment: is the slider animated or you have to click it to change slides

Comment: the slider is animated.

Comment: something like this `if ($( '.slides li' ).css( "display" )) {
       var result = $("#id-height").height(); 
    alert(result + " px");
      }` would work

Comment: nol, i am sorry but my jquery skills are horrible. I don't see how this would call the function every time the picture changes. Anyway, i tried putting it in my code and it didn't work. From my little knowledge I would imagine that I have to add the snippet of code in the jquery that woothemes provides, but i just can't find in their code where they do the transition. Here is the code that I've been playing with so far:

Comment: function getHeight(){
var heightLeft = document.getElementById("left-img").offsetHeight; 
if(heightLeft < 350){var y = (350 - heightLeft)/2;
document.getElementById("left-img").style.marginTop = y+"px";}
var heightRight = document.getElementById("id-height").offsetHeight;
if(heightRight<350){
var x = (350 - heightRight)/2;
document.getElementById("id-height").style.marginTop = x+"px";
}
else
document.getElementById("flexslider").style.height=height+"px";
}